# Implementing an Outlook 2007 style 'Group by box' using WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

In Microsoft Outlook 2007 it is possible to drag items (ie From, Subject) from the Inbox to a 'Group By Box' that appears above the Inbox grid.

- What is the proper term for that kind of box?
- Where do I find some examples/samples on how to implement in a Winforms application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may search for a third-party grid control with such feature. DevExpress [XtraGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/) [can do that](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/dataoperations.xml) but it is overloaded with features and you may consider it to be an overkill.

Comment: If we talk about 3rd-party controls, there is another cheap and lightweight but powerful [grid control with the built-in group box](http://10tec.com/winforms-grid/outlook-style-datagrid.aspx).